# Upgrading Java and Eclipse versions

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, migration

We have a project that uses Java 6 and Eclipse Indigo. We would like to upgrade to OpenJDK 8. After converting the configuration in Indigo, I understood that Indigo does not support OpenJDK 8. So we moved to Eclipse Kepler. But now, Kepler notifies me with the following error:

> The import org.apache.commons.cli cannot be resolved

How to solve it?

Comment: That just sounds like a problem with your project; e.g. it doesn't have the JAR file that defines that import in the project dependencies.  How are you doing your builds?  Managing your dependencies?

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to use Kepler instead of Indigo (different paths). Maybe that is why? how to install that lib?

Comment: Why Eclipse Kepler and not latest one?

Comment: That "lib" that you are talking about is not part of Eclipse.  It is a 3rd party JAR that you need to download and add to your project.  By the way, you didn't answer my questions.